# Suddenly NLog contains ReadAsync and WriteAsync HTTP log entries

Tags: .net-core, nlog, kestrel-http-server

Our software suddenly started logging the complete HTTP Headers, filling up the log files

```
[08:32:53.5245][Debug]ReadAsync[642] 47 45 54 20 2F
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4432
Connection: keep-alive

[08:32:53.5245][Debug]WriteAsync[201] 48 54 54 50
```

No changes were made to the nlog.config or the appsettings.json

The only change was a newer .net core runtime 2.1.16 in our installer

Appsettings:

```
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Trace",
    "System": "Warning",
    "Microsoft": "Warning"
  }
},
```

partial nlog.config

```xml
 <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
 <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
```

This problem does not occur on the development system

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the way to solve this was to first add the `${logger}` to the nlog.config layout output to trace the root.

This showed that the `KestrelConnectionLogger` was the source

With this, the following line could be added to the nlog.config

```xml
<logger name="KestrelConnectionLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
```

Comment: FYI, the `writeTo="blackhole"` ins't needed more these days. Just remove the `writeTo` attribute at all, then the messages are implicitly send to a blackhole